# how to use SignalR's round-tripping state?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

According to the documentation of SignalR's Hub (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) we can use something called "Round-tripping state". But I haven't figure out how to use on the .NET client side to use this feature.

Could you give me a simple example to use that feature between a server & a .NET client?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Search for state on this page https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs. Our docs kinda suck, but the content is there :).